# What causes this noise when I lift my foot off the brake pedal?

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, noise

I have a Honda Civic 2015 EX mid-option.

The brake noise can be heard when you are in drive mode at a complete stop and leave brake pedal. The noise is not continuous but only comes when you are lifting the foot off of brake pedal.

The important thing to note is that the noise doesn't come every day all the time you drive, but only sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of noise is it?

- Some brakes have a built in metal stripe which makes a noise to indicate worn-off brake pads. This should be a metallic screeching sound.
- Bad brake cylinders or leakage in the lines can cause the brake-pad to not entirely re-set after braking, so the pad keeps contact to the disc. This can also happen with a rusted handbrake-mechanism. This makes more of a grinding sound.
- Rusted brakes: Especially the rear brakes, if the vehicle stands for a longer time. Also using the handbrake on the standing vehicle. This often causes a more rhythmic sound with every revolution of the wheel

Some little noise right after you stood on the brake is quite normal, as the pads may still be softly touching the disc. This is especially if your discs are a bit worn and rusted.

It may help to inspect the brake with the wheel off. Look for grooves in the disc and severely rusted edges. The brake-pad should have minimum 4mm of material left on them - look in google images after what to look for. The disc / wheel should turn easily when lifted off the ground.

You can also see if one rim does get considerably hotter then the other ones -> Points to a defect brake cylinder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @daniel I believe it is not the worn-off break pads. During my last maintenance service with Honda about 7000km before they told me the brake pads are ok.

You may be right on the grinding sound which I should get checked. The total km on the vehicle is 70,000 km. I had the brake pads changed at 40K.

Comment: @Faheem Ahmad: Do you usually park with the handbrake on? Has the vehicle longer standing periods?

Comment: Just to let you know, I edited my comment above. And yes I always park with the handbrake on, a strict habit of mine, not sure if it is good! But I drive it to work & back every day except weekends.

Comment: @Faheem Ahmad: Did they also change the discs? A little rust-ring on the edge of the Disc could be the problem. My mechanic always speaks against using the the handbrake when not parking on a significant slope. Park-position or first gear should be enough. Reason is rusting of the pads to the disc will occur on the rear brakes if the vehicle stands for a longer time.

Comment: No they only changed the brake pads. Ah cool tip, I will stop using the handbrake parking from now on. I will also get the brake discs checked in the next session. Thanks a bunch!